# dataset getxml for one of the tables

Tags: dataset

C# 2005. I have a dataset with 3 tables, and I would like to get the xml for just one of these tables. Any idea?

TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet from http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/MappingDataSetToXMLAndBackwards.aspx. I'd suggest you read the whole article.

`DataTable.WriteXML` is the method you need for just one table.

Something like:

```
private void SingleTableToXml(DataSet ds)
{
    ds.Tables["myTable"].WriteXML(Server.MapPath("mytable.xml"),XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
}
```

Comment: This will force me to write it to the Hard disc, which i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: There are numerous overloads for WriteXML so you don't have to write to disc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx